# SSRS - Display current grouping field values in report page header

Tags: reporting-services

I'm using SQL Server Data Tools 2012 (Visual Studio 2010) and have a multi-tab report that does a page break on each combination of SalesTerritory and ProductType.

I can label the worksheet tabs of the resulting downloaded Excel spreadsheet by adding a group-level PageName property expression in the Properties window that concatenates the two current grouping criteria values:

```
=Lookup(Fields!SalesRegionID.Value, Fields!SalesRegionID.Value,  
        Fields!SalesRegionCode.Value, "SalesRegion") + " " +
 Lookup(Fields!ProductTypeID.Value, Fields!ProductTypeID.Value,  
        Fields!ProductTypeName.Value, "ProductType")
```

What I'd like to do now is add the same string to the page header of each report page.  I can't simply add the above expression in a text box since "field references outside of a data region must be contained within aggregate functions which specify a dataset scope."

So, how do I scope the references in order to display the same string on both current tab 
and the page header of each worksheet?

Answer (score 3):

It turns out that the PageName property that I assigned at the group level is also available as a global field.  If you add a text box to the page header and open its expression dialog, you will find a field in the Built-in Fields category called "PageName".  Double-clicking this will add the following expression:

```
"=Globals!PageName"
```

That does it!