# How to mimic values in multi page SSRS Report

Tags: sql, t-sql, reporting-services

I need a lab report that has several pages. Each test has a unique reference number and I would like it to appear in the header according to what I have on the page. At the moment I only see one reference number and it remains unchanged after switching to another page. See attached image.[image]

If possible, I would like to get rid of the SampleNo column so that its value is only in the header

Comment: This looks like it might be a way to tackle this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18493822/ssrs-display-current-grouping-field-values-in-report-page-header

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to reference the the textbox in your tablix that contains the "Sample No.".

Click the textbox that you have highlighted in the tablix, show the properties window (F4 in Visual Studio - can't remember in Report Builder, I think View/Properties).
Find the `Name` property of the textbox, this is often the name of the field it contains but not always.

In the example below the textbox name is 'oYear`

[image]

Next, set the expression in your header to be something like

```
=FIRST(ReportItems!oYear.Value)
```

Change `oYear` to whatever textbox name in your tablix is.

`ReportItems` refers to the rendered object name so here we just get the first on each page.

Here the first two pages from a small sample of data which groups by year.

[image: page1]

[image: page2]